# Use mouse to rotate a rectangle

Tags: javascript, rotation, processing, angle

I have the rectangle pointing at the mouse. What I want: when I lift the mouse and click and drag that the rectangle rotates further.

Or that I can click on any corner to rotate the rectangle. Just like you would with your finger and a sheet of paper.

```
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  push();
  translate(150, 150);
  rotate(angle);

  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  rect(-100, -75, 200, 150);

  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  line(-100, -75, 100, -75);

  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  point(0, 0);

  pop();
}

function mouseDragged() {
  m_angle = atan2(mouseY - 150, mouseX - 150);
  angle = /* MAGIC FORMULA HERE */ m_angle;
}
```

https://editor.p5js.org/jwglazebrook/sketches/p2pnhPSZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Problem:

The issue with your code is that you need to store the offset from the initial mouse click to the new dragged point.

> The Solution:

To fix the jerky behavior we just have to store the previous mouse angle and box angle and compare the difference with the dragged mouse angle.

> The Code:

```
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  push();
  translate(150, 150);
  rotate(angle);

  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  rect(-100, -75, 200, 150);

  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  line(-100, -75, 100, -75);

  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  point(0, 0);

  pop();
}

let c_angle = 0;
let q_angle = 0;

function mousePressed() {
  c_angle = atan2(mouseY - 150, mouseX - 150); //The initial mouse rotation
  q_angle = angle; //Initial box rotation
}

function mouseDragged() {
  m_angle = atan2(mouseY - 150, mouseX - 150);

  let dangle = m_angle - c_angle; //How much the box needs to be rotated
  if (dangle>=360) dangle-=360; //clamping
  if (dangle<0) dangle+=360; //clamping
  angle =  q_angle + dangle; //Apply the rotation
  if (angle>=360) angle -= 360; //clamping
}
```

Comment: Legend! Works like perfect! I also love the variable 'dangle' as a common saying in my parts is "What's the angle of the dangle?"